# Can i access/use a single value in a multi-valued list box using Infopath?

Tags: infopath

i have a multivalued list box "Release Scope" and it is just 3 values.

[image]

i try to use a Rule that whenever the Value 'contains' "Targeted" then something will happen.

this doesn't work. how can i access the values to perform logic accordingly in my form?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into possibly this same issue, I couldn't find a solution online, but after some poking around in InfoPath 2010, I found it.

For a condition based on multi-valued selection, when setting up the conditional rule, in the field selection, you have to go to Select a field or group... > Your MultiValued Listbox > Show Advanced View > Select: All occurences of Value

This will then allow you to use contains or not contains and will check that each selected item meets your criteria.

In your second screenshot, your condition only checks Value which will only check the first item selected in your MultiValued Listbox.

Comment: Wow, 2 hours of googling, finally found your answer, which did the trick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to hide the section, based on a rule where a field does not contain "Targeted".

---

Here is a test form that shows how you can apply rules to show and hide a section.
[Test form for InfoPath](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B82278sL4zFxZjRuaUlOUUlfa2s/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please explain. I don't see the logic of how that can work or be implemented.  I add a Form Load event that does what, there's not an action for 'hide a section'.

Comment: Appologies, you are right there is no formatting on Form load. I have done a test form for you, check it out how I have applied the rules.

Here is a link to a test form:
Test InfoPath Form - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B82278sL4zFxZjRuaUlOUUlfa2s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: i'm sorry but this is not the answer. i'm asking about a MULTI-VALUED list - your answer was just simple form rules applies to checkbox binary value. if you could try my example and show me how it would work, using a multi-valued list item that would be great.

Comment: This works for me except for one thing. I have five choices. If a choice is selected I want to unhide a section below for that choice. Users can pick more than one choice which should unhide all selected choices. However, only the first selected choice unhides the following section. No matter how many I choose after that the sections don't hide.

Comment: can you show me the pic of the Rule you have that actually works even for the one choice?

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work, if not please attach a sample form, so I can help.